# why rails console always in replace mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

rails console always in replace mode, when pressing "left arrow" the character get removed,the problem is exist after pressing "insert" button also. After Reload command also same issue is existing. After pressing left arrow ,then i cant able to type any character on that line.

Comment: Tried by resetting (terminal configuration) , then also the same issue

Comment: although `rails console` is working fine for me ...try `pry`

Comment: @RajarshiDas Rails console and pry are have massive difference ?

Comment: @errakesh Pry is an alternative IRB which you can add as a gem: https://github.com/pry/pry

Comment: @ChrisBarthol ,but this issue is only in me development environment, others are not facing this issue.

Comment: @errakesh : Try using better_errors gem. Then you could get the console on your browser window.

Comment: Thanks @rahulv now i got a console in my web browser.

Comment: @RajarshiDas when i use pry also the the character get removed when pressing left arrow.